# How to view QString values in debugger with Qt 5.5.1

Tags: qt, qstring, debuggervisualizer, qt5.5

Does anyone know how to view QString values in the debugger for Qt 5.5.1 (QtCreator 5.3.1)?

I have tried various things found online, from enabling/disabling GDB pretty printer, display QString format etc. Nothing seems to work.

(Compiler - MSVC 2013 - 32 bit)

Edit- image:
[image]

Many thanks,
Michael

Comment: what do you see instead? `not accessible`?

Comment: I just see the internals of QString, QArrayData and so on. (Yes inside Qt Creator. - All my colleagues see the same behaviour also)

Comment: " from enabling/disabling GDB pretty printer” - that sounds weird, creator should use the windows debugging tools (cdb) by default on Windows. Which debugger have you configured in your Kit?

Comment: Just trying tips I found online. How do I see which debugger I've got configured? I've not changed it, so presumably the right one. Everythign else works ok, just displaying string. Also my other colleagues see the same problem.

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-50322

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in QT Creator 3.5.1. when webengine was linked to the project (for some reason)

Fix is in Qt Creator 3.6.1. Details are here: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-15580

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem. And I find the solution.

My Qt is 5.9.2. IDE is Qt Creator 4.3.1.

Click `Tools`->`options`->`Debugger`->`Local & Expresions`->`Use Debugging Helper`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the QString::data() function or data_ptr pointer in your QString class.

Comment: That's not really a solution. I want to use the debugger, not print the value.

Comment: @Dynite no, I mean you can look at the "data/data_ptr" element of the object in your debugger to see the actual data :o

Comment: Doesn't work - the only way to see the data is to visualise the memory of the QArrayData sub object.

Comment: I just checked on my own windows Qt (same version as yours Qt 5.5.1 and Qt Creator 3.5.1). When I look at a QString I just see my variable name (and its type) then under it is the list of QChars by index with its contents. I am not seeing the other members of the QString (i.e. I can see the contents of the array). Which compiler / debugger are you using in your kit? Mine is: `mingw 4.9.2` and `GNU gdb 7.8 for mingw 4.9.2`

Comment: Info is in the question: "Compiler - MSVC 2013 - 32 bit"

Comment: ahh.. totally missed that sorry, will take a look at the msvc version next week.